# Moen shower trim handle replacement

Tags: shower

[image]

[image]

I have a white Moen shower that came with the house. The diverter leaks but there not really any white replacements. So I went to home Depot to buy a new set and since I don't know if I have a posi valve currently, I just decided to change out the fixtures. Good on the shower and spout but I can't get whatever is behind the handle/trim to come off.any help on what I'm screwing up so I can pull and replace the handle would be appreciated. Also, I have no idea what a posi temp is but if you can tell by the pick and let me know if that's what I have it'd be appreciated as well. Thank you

Comment: is there a small hex screw on the side ? and what is in the center hole ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a screw, ( usually Philips) down in the hole in the temperature stop   ( Grey Thing) remove the screw and that part will come off. You may have to pull hard, so turn the water off to then house or you will get a shower. Then the sleave slides off and the trim plate can be removed.
The "Positemp" is an anti-scald mixing valve. It can be identified by the screw holes in the trim plate that are diagonally opposed. Older first gen Moen valves have 2 holes closer to each other at the bottom of the trim plate.

Comment: generally the moen shower's I have taken apart has a clip that holds the valve in place so you can remove the escutcheon plate and access the integrated shutoffs.  also the piece that usually goes bad is the o-ring on the valve which can be replaced though I've never bothered as the moen valves are lifetime?  I got my replacements free at homedepot.